# Java httpSession is not maintained

Tags: java, tomcat

I just migrated the application from an aged Tomcat server (6.x) to Tomcat 8.

```
Master: Apache http server
Slave: Apache Tomcat application server
```

I use the **ProxyPass** setting to connect the Apache http server to the Tomcat server.
Works well, except the Tomcat server does not maintain `httpSession` between two `httpServletRequests`. The second request is suppost to pick-up some values from the `httpSession`, but the `session` is new.
Using the Tomcat server on it's own (port 8080) `session` is maintained between two requests.

I know there is a trick to this, but I'm unable to find it, regardless how many times I'm reading up and down the Apache manual.

```
httpd-ajp.conf: ProxyPass /MY_APP ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/MY_APP
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you use HTTPS to connect to Apache httpd, you must use the `secure` option on the http connector (in `server.xml`) - see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Attributes  - If you don't, the "secure cookie" is ignored by the "insecure" tomcat connector

Comment: @geert3 There is no HTTP connector in this scenario, just an AJP connector.

Comment: But is the httpd connection over HTTPS?

Comment: @geert3 You don't appear to have understood the question. HTTPS starts at the browser or client, and terminates at the Apache HTTPD. From there to Tomcat it is plaintext AJP.

Comment: @EJP Cookies sent from browser to httpd via HTTPS have a "secure" bit set. They are forwarded to tomcat via either http or ajp connectors. If the cookie is "secure", the connector needs to be secure too, in order for the tomcat webapp to "see" the cookie. Otherwise the cookie is discarded, and it is as if each request is from a new session, which is what the OP is observing.

Comment: I got the similar issue. Any solution here? Please advise.